# Overriding QuerySet.delete() in Django

Tags: django

I have a Django model that holds settings core to the function of an app. You should never delete this model. I'm trying to enforce this application-wide. I've disabled the delete function in the admin, and also disabled the delete method on the model, but QuerySet has it's own delete method. Example:

```
MyModel.objects.all()[0].delete() # Overridden, does nothing

MyModel.objects.all().delete() # POOF!
```

Ironically, the Django docs say has this to say about why delete() is a method on QuerySet and not Manager:

> This is a safety mechanism to prevent you from accidentally requesting Entry.objects.delete(), and deleting all the entries.

How having to include `.all()` is a "safety mechanism" is questionable to say the least. Instead, this effectively creates a backdoor that can't be closed by conventional means (overriding the manager).

Anyone have a clue how to override this method on something as core as QuerySet without monkey-patching the source?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can override a `Manager's` default `QuerySet` by overriding the `Manager.get_query_set()` method.

#### Example:

```
class MyQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):

    def delete(self):
        pass  # you can throw an exception


class NoDeleteManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return MyQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

class MyModel(models.Model)
    field1 = ..
    field2 = ..


    objects = NoDeleteManager()
```

Now, `MyModel.objects.all().delete()` will do nothing.

For more informations: [Modifying initial Manager QuerySets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset)

Comment: Well, that's a big duh on my part. Should have thought of that myself, but thanks for supplementing my aging brain's failings ;).

Comment: Method from django 1.6+ is called `get_queryset(self)`.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you can do this a bit cleaner with [QuerySet.as_manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#creating-a-manager-with-queryset-methods).  You could remove the above manager class and just do: `objects = MyQuerySet.as_manager()`

Comment: As of now (Django 1.11) the "get_queryset" method looks like  `def get_queryset(self):  return MyQuerySet(model=self.model, using=self._db, hints=self._hints)`

Answer (score 12):

### mixin approach

https://gist.github.com/dnozay/373571d8a276e6b2af1a

use a similar recipe as @manji posted,

```
class DeactivateQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    '''
    QuerySet whose delete() does not delete items, but instead marks the
    rows as not active, and updates the timestamps
    '''
    def delete(self):
        self.deactivate()

    def deactivate(self):
        deleted = now()
        self.update(active=False, deleted=deleted)

    def active(self):
        return self.filter(active=True)


class DeactivateManager(models.Manager):
    '''
    Manager that returns a DeactivateQuerySet,
    to prevent object deletion.
    '''
    def get_query_set(self):
        return DeactivateQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def active(self):
        return self.get_query_set().active()
```

and create a mixin:

```
class DeactivateMixin(models.Model):
    '''
    abstract class for models whose rows should not be deleted but
    items should be 'deactivated' instead.

    note: needs to be the first abstract class for the default objects
    manager to be replaced on the subclass.
    '''
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, editable=False, db_index=True)
    deleted = models.DateTimeField(default=None, editable=False, null=True)
    objects = DeactivateManager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

### other interesting stuff

- http://datahackermd.com/2013/django-soft-deletion/
- https://github.com/hearsaycorp/django-livefield