# Readonly models in Django admin interface?

Tags: django, django-admin, readonly

How can I make a model completely read-only in the admin interface? It's for a kind of log table, where I'm using the admin features to search, sort, filter etc, but there is no need to modify the log.

In case this looks like a duplicate, here's *not* what I'm trying to do:

- I'm not looking for readonly *fields* (even making every field readonly would still let you create new records)
- I'm not looking to create a readonly *user*: every user should be readonly.

Comment: this feature should be coming soon: https://github.com/django/django/pull/5297

Comment: `has_view_permission` was finally implemented in Django 2.1. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51641149 below.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

See https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10539/

```
class ReadOnlyAdminMixin(object):
    """Disables all editing capabilities."""
    change_form_template = "admin/view.html"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReadOnlyAdminMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.readonly_fields = [f.name for f in self.model._meta.get_fields()]

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(ReadOnlyAdminMixin, self).get_actions(request)
        del_action = "delete_selected"
        if del_action in actions:
            del actions[del_action]
        return actions

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        pass

    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        pass

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        pass
```

**templates/admin/view.html**

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
  <div class="submit-row">
    <a href="../">{% blocktrans %}Back to list{% endblocktrans %}</a>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**templates/admin/view.html (for Grappelli)**

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}
  <footer class="grp-module grp-submit-row grp-fixed-footer">
    <header style="display:none"><h1>{% trans "submit options"|capfirst context "heading" %}</h1></header>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="../" class="grp-button grp-default">{% blocktrans %}Back to list{% endblocktrans %}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </footer>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Seems legit. It's been so long since I've used Django though, might wait to see what other commenters have to say.

Comment: Is this a mixin for the `Model`, or for the `ModelAdmin`?

Comment: It's for the `ModelAdmin`.

Comment: For Django 1.8 and later, get_all_field_names is deprecated. [Backwards compatible way to get them](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api). [Short way to get them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106295/django-get-list-of-model-fields).

Comment: You can use has_add_permission

Answer (score 78):

The admin is for editing, not just viewing (you won't find a "view" permission). In order to achieve what you want you'll have to forbid adding, deleting, and make all fields readonly:

```
class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin):

    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

(if you forbid changing you won't even get to see the objects)

For some untested code that tries to automate setting all fields read-only see my answer to [Whole model as read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920371/whole-model-as-read-only/7965193#7965193)

EDIT: This makes all fields read-only:

```
readonly_fields = [field.name for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields()]
```

EDIT: QuerySet.delete() may still bulk delete objects. To get around this, provide your own "objects" manager and corresponding QuerySet subclass which doesn't delete - see [Overriding QuerySet.delete() in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459616/overriding-queryset-delete-in-django/6459797#6459797)

Comment: P.S.: and yes, as in the other answer, the way to go is probably to define those three things in a ReadOnlyAdmin class, and then subclass from that whereever you need that behaviour. Could even get fancy and allow the definition of groups/permissions which _are_ allowed to edit, and then return True correspondingly (and use get_readonly_fields() which has access to the request and therefore the current user).

Comment: almost perfect. could I greedily ask if there's a way to not have rows link to an edit page? (again, there's no need to zoom in on any row, and no need to edit anything)

Comment: If you set your ModelAdmin's list_display_links to something that evaluates as False (like an empty list/tuple), ModelAdmin.__init__() sets list_display_links to all columns (except the action checkbox) - see options.py. I guess that's done to _ensure_ there are links. So I would override __init__() in a ReadOnlyAdmin, call the parent one then set list_display_links to an empty list or tuple. Given that you now won't have links to the readonly change forms, probably best to create a parameter / class attribute for this - I wouldn't think that to be the generally desired behaviour. Hth

Comment: Regarding readonly_fields being set from the model, this probably won't work if you override the form and add other fields... basing it on the _actual_ form fields is probably better.

Comment: This didn't work:

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(RegistrationStatusAdmin, self).__init__(*args)
        self.display_links=[]

Comment: Admittedly, this is probably the closest thing the OP asked for, but this isn't really ideal because you're not explicitly giving the user readonly access. You're hardcoding it into the modeladmin, but then giving the user "change" access, which is unintuitive. Ideally, you'd give the user explicit "view" permission and then rescind their add/change/delete permission. Unfortunately, the Django core devs are uninterested in this preferable solution.

Comment: Yeah if there were "View" permissions in Django this question would have probably not come up. :-)

Comment: I don't see why you would downvote this answer - it's just dealing with an existing mess! Django ticket #820 opened 9 years ago "wontfix". I still can't think of a cleaner ReadOnlyModelAdmin. Btw the ideal way wouldn't explicitly give a user "view" permission - if they don't have it already (possibly "implied" through "change" permission) then the user is not allowed to view... as per current admin logic the model would not show up on that user's admin screen at all.

Comment: Can prevent user's saved changes from persisting by `def save_model(..):` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5364408/962996)

Answer (score 58):

Here are two classes I am using to make a model and/or it's inlines read only.

For model admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin

class ReadOnlyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = []

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return list(self.readonly_fields) + \
               [field.name for field in obj._meta.fields] + \
               [field.name for field in obj._meta.many_to_many]


    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

class MyModelAdmin(ReadOnlyAdmin):
    pass
```

For inlines:

```
class ReadOnlyTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    extra = 0
    can_delete = False
    editable_fields = []
    readonly_fields = []
    exclude = []

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return list(self.readonly_fields) + \
               [field.name for field in self.model._meta.fields
                if field.name not in self.editable_fields and
                   field.name not in self.exclude]

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False


class MyInline(ReadOnlyTabularInline):
    pass
```

Comment: How you apply both classes to one sub class. E.g. if I have normal fields and inlines in a class? Can I extend both?

Comment: @timo use these classes [as mixins](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/mixins-and-python)

Comment: `has_add_permission` in `ReadOnlyAdmin` takes only request as a parameter

Comment: the has_change_permission() also need to be overridden.
    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):

Answer (score 17):

with django 2.2+, readonly admin can be as simple as:

```py
class ReadOnlyAdminMixin:
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False


class LogEntryAdmin(ReadOnlyAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'user', 'action_flag', 'content_type', 'object_repr')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks~

Answer (score 13):

If you want the user become aware that he/she cannot edit it, 2 pieces are missing on the first solution. You have remove the delete action!

```
class MyAdmin(ModelAdmin)
    def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(MyAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        if 'delete_selected' in actions:
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions
```

Second: the readonly solution works fine on plain models. But it does **NOT** work if you have an inherited model with foreign keys. Unfortunately, I don't know the solution for that yet. A good attempt is:

[Whole model as read-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920371/whole-model-as-read-only)

But it does not work for me either.

And a final note, if you want to think on a broad solution, you have to enforce that each inline has to be readonly too.

Answer (score 11):

Actually you can try this simple solution:

```
class ReadOnlyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    actions = None
    list_display_links = None
    # more stuff here

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False
```

- `actions = None`: avoids showing the dropdown with the "Delete selected ..." option
- `list_display_links = None`: avoids clicking in columns to edit that object
- `has_add_permission()` returning False avoids creating new objects for that model

Comment: This forbids opening any instance for viewing the fields, however if one's fine with just listing, then it works.

Answer (score 11):

This was added in to Django 2.1 which was released on 8/1/18!

`ModelAdmin.has_view_permission()` is just like the existing has_delete_permission, has_change_permission and has_add_permission. You can read about it in the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_view_permission)

From the release notes:

> This allows giving users read-only access to models in the admin.
>   ModelAdmin.has_view_permission() is new. The implementation is
>   backwards compatible in that there isn’t a need to assign the “view”
>   permission to allow users who have the “change” permission to edit
>   objects.

Comment: The superuser will still be able to modify the objects in the admin interface though, right?

Comment: That is correct, unless you override one of these methods to change the behavior to disallow superusers' access.

Answer (score 6):

If the accepted answer doesn't work for you, try this:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    readonly_fields = []
    for field in self.model._meta.fields:
        readonly_fields.append(field.name)

    return readonly_fields
```

Answer (score 6):

Compiling @darklow and @josir 's excellent answers, plus adding a bit more to remove "Save" and "Save and Continue" buttons leads to (in Python 3 syntax):

```
class ReadOnlyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """Provides a read-only view of a model in Django admin."""
    readonly_fields = []

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        """ customize add/edit form to remove save / save and continue """
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False
        extra_context['show_save'] = False
        return super().change_view(request, object_id, extra_context=extra_context)

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super().get_actions(request)
        if 'delete_selected' in actions:
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        return list(self.readonly_fields) + \
           [field.name for field in obj._meta.fields] + \
           [field.name for field in obj._meta.many_to_many]

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

and then you use like

```
class MyModelAdmin(ReadOnlyAdmin):
    pass
```

I've only tried this with Django 1.11 / Python 3.

Comment: It's been a very long time since I've used Django. Can anyone else vouch for this?

Comment: @SteveBennettㄹ there are lots of variations on the requirements that this addresses... this answer is not water-tight... suggest the explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36019597/2586761 and the answer you commented on https://stackoverflow.com/a/33543817/2586761 as more complete than the accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

With Django 2.2 I do it like this:

```py
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('all', 'the', 'necessary', 'fields')
    actions = None # Removes the default delete action in list view

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Comment: with django 2.2, the `readonly_fields` and `actions` lines are not necessary

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer should work, but this will also preserve the display order of the readonly fields. You also don't have to hardcode the model with this solution.

```
class ReadonlyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
      super(ReadonlyAdmin, self).__init__(model, admin_site)
      self.readonly_fields = [field.name for field in filter(lambda f: not f.auto_created, model._meta.fields)]

   def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
       return False
   def has_add_permission(self, request, obj=None):
       return False
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same requirement when needing to make all fields readonly for certain users in django admin ended up leveraging on django module "django-admin-view-permission" without rolling my own code. If you need more fine grained control  to explicitly define which fields then you would need to extend the module. You can check out the plugin in action [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6Doj2LOIlo&t=284s)

Answer (score 1):

I have written a generic class to handle ReadOnly view depending on User permissions, including inlines ;)

In models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    ...
    def is_readonly(self):
        if self.is_superuser:
            return False
        # make readonly all users not in "admins" group
        adminGroup = Group.objects.filter(name="admins")
        if adminGroup in self.groups.all():
            return False
        return True
```

In admin.py:

```
# read-only user filter class for ModelAdmin
class ReadOnlyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # keep initial readonly_fields defined in subclass
        self._init_readonly_fields = self.readonly_fields
        # keep also inline readonly_fields
        for inline in self.inlines:
            inline._init_readonly_fields = inline.readonly_fields
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    # customize change_view to disable edition to readonly_users
    def change_view( self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None ):
        context = extra_context or {}
        # find whether it is readonly or not 
        if request.user.is_readonly():
            # put all fields in readonly_field list
            self.readonly_fields = [ field.name for field in self.model._meta.get_fields() if not field.auto_created ]
            # readonly mode fer all inlines
            for inline in self.inlines:
                inline.readonly_fields = [field.name for field in inline.model._meta.get_fields() if not field.auto_created]
            # remove edition buttons
            self.save_on_top = False
            context['show_save'] = False
            context['show_save_and_continue'] = False
        else:
            # if not readonly user, reset initial readonly_fields
            self.readonly_fields = self._init_readonly_fields
            # same for inlines
            for inline in self.inlines:
                inline.readonly_fields = self._init_readonly_fields
        return super().change_view(
                    request, object_id, form_url, context )
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # disable saving model for readonly users
        # just in case we have a malicious user...
        if request.user.is_readonly():
            # si és usuari readonly no guardem canvis
            return False
        # if not readonly user, save model
        return super().save_model( request, obj, form, change )
```

Then, we can just inherit normally our classes in admin.py:

```
class ContactAdmin(ReadOnlyAdmin):
    list_display = ("name","email","whatever")
    readonly_fields = ("updated","created")
    inlines = ( PhoneInline, ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

### read-only => views permission

1. `pipenv install django-admin-view-permission`
2. add 'admin_view_permission' to INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py.like this:
   `INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'admin_view_permission',
3. python manage.py migrate
4. python manage.py runserver `6666`

#### ok.have fun with the 'views' permission