# Customize user's admin panel permission only to read(not delete,edit or add)

Tags: django, django-admin, django-permissions

I want a end-user to use admin-panel to see the obejcts created, but i dont want him to add-delete or edit any object created. But in django admin panel user settings, only permissions are add, delete or edit. Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265328/readonly-models-in-django-admin-interface

Answer (score 0):

Firs you create a admin panel user with `python manage.py runserver` and go to the `localhost:your_port/admin` login with account go to user change user active , superuser, admin status