# Change Database used in Django session based on User logged on

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I want to give access to the Django Admin to some people, but only have them be able to read (no update/delete/create powers). Unfortunately this seems largely unsupported in Django.

The solution my team came up with was to use [Multiple Databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/multi-db/), and have one of the configurations be a read only one. However, is there a way to say somewhere in Django "Get the database that X user is assigned, and read from that" ?

(Also if someone has a non painful suggestion on how to do the read-only admin, I would appreciate it. The use case is just that there is a lot of data that needs to be searched through and looked at by people, and the admin tool already has this installed).

Comment: maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265328/readonly-models-in-django-admin-interface

Comment: I think it would be much simpler to implement the a model view than going with multiple databases.