# Read only models and displayed as a list in django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to display a model from db onto my django admin. What I want do with it is just simply display the details, no editing. is there a way to somehow "disable" the CRUD functions of a model in the django admin ? I can't seem to find a way. my current django version is 2.1.1. thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes You can do one thing,
Every admin has ge_urls method, Override that method and Don't Call Super. Make your custom url and view that can display only readonly fields.

Comment: how ? sorry i'm new to django.

Comment: forget that comment, just follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265328/readonly-models-in-django-admin-interface] link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use read only fields.

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    fields = ['test-field-a']
    readonly_fields = fields

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

Answer (score 1):

For read-only model you can use app [`django-readonly-model`](https://github.com/dorosch/django-readonly-model)

Install using pip:

```
pip install django-readonly-model
```

Add 'readonly_model' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'readonly_model',
]
```

And just use:

```
from django.db import models

class Directory(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        read_only_model = True
```

if you try to record something, you will get an exception:

```
>>> Directory.objects.create(name='kg')
...
readonly_model.exceptions.ReadOnlyModel: Model 'app.models.Directory' is read-only
```