# Deleting uploaded files in Django

Tags: django, delete-file

I have the following code to delete a file:

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
import os

class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/%Y/%m/%d')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.docfile.name)
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        os.rmdir(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.docfile.name))
        super(Document,self).delete(*args,**kwargs)
```

It manages to delete the objects I ask it to in my views.py but when I reupload a file of the same name it seems as though the original file still exists since I'll get "output_1.txt" instead of "output.txt".

This is the code I use to delete:

```
def delete_matrix():
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    documents.delete()
```

Am I not deleting the file from the database? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your problem is that you are overriding the `delete()` method on the model but you are calling the `delete` method on the `QuerySet` returned by the default manager (`Documents.object.all().delete()`).  These are 2 separate methods so there are 2 ways of fixing this.

1.In the `delete` method of the model, replace the line

```
os.rmdir(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.docfile.name))
```

by

```
os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.docfile.name))
```

AND, call the delete method for each object separately.  Replace

```
Document.objects.all().delete()
```

with

```
documents = Document.objects.all()
for document in documents:
    document.delete()
```

2.Replace the default manager to return a custom `QuerySet` which overrides the `delete()` method.  This is explained in [Overriding `QuerySet.delete()` in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459616/overriding-queryset-delete-in-django)

Comment: no I didn't get an exception, os.remove didn't seem to fix the error either.

Comment: We ended up with the same answer! I fixed this last night and I realized I shouldn't be overriding the delete method at all, I just added os.remove(...) after document.delete()

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```py
document = Document.objects.get(pk=pk)
# if `save`=True, changes are saved to the db else only the file is deleted
document.docfile.delete(save=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a much simpler code:

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.docfile:
        self.docfile.delete()
    super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another solution

```
def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
   os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.qr_code.name))
   super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would subscribe to the model's [`post_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/signals/#post-delete) signal instead, to ensure that the clean-up code is called regardless of whether the deletion was initiated by calling the model method or the QuerySet method.

```
@receiver(
    post_delete,
    sender=Document,
    dispatch_uid="clean_up_after_document_deletion",
)
def clean_up_after_document_deletion(
    sender: type[Document],
    instance: Document,
    **kwargs,
):
    os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, instance.docfile.name))
```

*P.S. The post-delete Django Signals API hasn't changed since Django 1, so it  should work as is for all versions of Django, from 1 to 5 (currently, the latest).*