# How to use a pre_delete signal to universally prevent delete?

Tags: django, django-signals

I have a common field `is_active = models.BooleanField()` on all my models.

I want to create a universal override to the delete function so that instead of removing records from the database, `is_active = False`.

I understand the best way to do this is a `pre_delete` signal rather than overriding `delete()` itself as `delete()` [is not called in bulk operations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods).

I have tried the following implementation:

```
@receiver(pre_delete)
def delete_obj(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """Override delete() to set object to inactive."""

    return instance.is_active == False
```

However this still results in objects being deleted from the database. I assume this is because `delete()` is still called after `pre_delete`. How do I correct this?

From the docs:

> Note that the delete() method for an object is not necessarily called when deleting objects in bulk using a QuerySet or as a result of a cascading delete. To ensure customized delete logic gets executed, you can use pre_delete and/or post_delete signals.

Comment: I think the only possible way is to override the `delete` function. you may also want to consider the case if the deletion is cascaded by the means of relationships.

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb thanks but that won't help if I am bulk deleting items in a queryset because `delete()` is not called then.

Comment: It is possible to use pre_delete but instead of reinventing the wheel you could use something like https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html#softdeletablemanager

Comment: @iklinac thanks that's helpful, if possible I'd like to understand the reason behind this problem and the code/syntax to fix it.

Comment: @alias51 for bulk operation you can iterate over your queryset and manually calling your custom `delete` method. This is of-course less performant, but it will preserve data integrity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding QuerySet.delete() in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459616/overriding-queryset-delete-in-django)

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb Unfortunately I don't see how it applies. It doesn't reference why `post_delete()` can't interrupt `delete()` or how I would go about doing that.

Comment: @alias51 check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459616/overriding-queryset-delete-in-django.

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb Thanks but that's the same link?

Answer (score 1):

You want to **replace** the logic of original method (in this case, perform update instead of delete) **not** to **extend** it.

**Signals** are to **extend** the **main** method **logic**, not replace it.

In `pre_` signals - run some additional logic before the action (maybe even modify the object). In `post_` signals - run some additional logic after the main action. But the main action is still run - and it should - it was called rightfully in the code - signals are not supposed to replace it.

Like extending method on the model: you will add some logic before or after calling `super().method()` - that is how signals work.

In case of replacing method logic with another one - when overriding the method `super()` most probably will not be called so no original actions be performed.

---

So, to replace `delete()` with custom logic you can override both model's `delete()` method and use custom QuerySet for model with overriden `delete()` method so when calling `delete()` either on model instance or QuerySet - it will perform update instead.

---

[Link to surce code where QuerySet delete is performed](https://github.com/django/django/blob/89abecc75d7eadab681f29be5237972c6c2f997b/django/db/models/deletion.py#L386):

- `pre_delete` signal is sent
- `delete_batch` is performed
- `post_delete` signal is sent